# Hide Toolbar items in Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

In AndroidStudio 4.2 Canary
I want to hide the settings (toolbar) in gallery fragment.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

But I got the error: *unresolved reference*.
Code used in gallery fragment:

```kotlin
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {    
    private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        menu!!.findItem(R.id.action_settings).isVisble(view: false)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery)
        galleryViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default activity template adds a `Settings` menu item at the Activity level. If you only want it to appear on your Home fragment you need to remove it from the activity level `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and instead add it to your `HomeFragment`'s `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Note that in a Fragment, you must call [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#sethasoptionsmenu) if you want a Fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to be called.